# After restarting bot using persistent buttons, function errors

Tags: python, discord.py

I believe i've set up my persistent button correctly as it syncs fine how ever I believe its an error with my code which I'm unsure of whats causing it.

The "embed = self.command()" works fine on the first run of the bot but after the restart it errors "'NoneType' object is not callable" at the embed = ... section

Note the genEmbed code is all for testing currently and would be changed in future for my needs

````
@client.event
async def on_ready():
    try:
        synced = await client.tree.sync()
        print(f"Synced {len(synced)} commands")
        print(f"Active in {str(len(client.guilds))} servers")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    try:
        client.add_view(genButton(command=None,channel=None))
        print("Synced buttons")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Failed to sync buttons {e}")

def test():

    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xe5ff00,
                    timestamp=datetime.datetime.now())
    embed.set_author(name=f"Code")
    embed.add_field(name="**__Code__**",value=f"```test```",inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="text",icon_url="*icon url*")

    return embed

class genButton(discord.ui.View):
    def __init__(self, command,channel):
        super().__init__(timeout=None)
        self.command = command
        self.channel = channel

    @discord.ui.button(label="Generate",custom_id="gen_button",emoji=None,style=discord.ButtonStyle.success)
    async def generate(self, interaction: discord.Interaction, button: discord.ui.Button):
        embed = self.command()
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed,ephemeral=True)

@client.tree.command(name="embed")
async def genEmbed(interaction: discord.Interaction, title: Optional[str], chan: Optional[str], step1: Optional[str], step2: Optional[str], notes: Optional[str]):
    channelid = chan
    embed = discord.Embed(colour=0xe6c12d)
    embed.set_author(name=title)
    embed.add_field(name="channel",value=f"<#{chan}>")
    if step1 != None:
        embed.add_field(name="Step 1",value=step1,inline=True)
    if step2 != None:
        embed.add_field(name="Step 2",value=step2,inline=True)
    if notes != None:
        embed.add_field(name="Notes",value=notes)
    embed.set_footer(text="text",icon_url="*icon url*")

    await interaction.response.send_message("Sent embed")
    channel = client.get_channel(int(channelid))
    await channel.send(embed=embed,view=genButton(test,channel))
````

I've tried numerous amounts of times changing around little parts just to try and get it to work but every time it errors at that section, I assume its some tiny part of my code causing it but im not too sure

Comment: When you say "restart", do you mean Ctrl-C and run the script again?

Comment: @TimRoberts just closing the program and opening it again?

Comment: Well, you're doing `genButton(command=None,channel=None)`.  Naturally `self.command()` produces that error.

Comment: @TimRoberts but why is that? the command and channel parameters are only there in relation the persistent button. Would I just change it to `genButton(command=self.command, channel=None)`?

Comment: That obviously won't work, because you're calling it in a non-class function, so `self` does not exist.  What are `command` and `channel` supposed to be?  Who is going to fill them in?  You can't pass an object from one execution to another.

Comment: But can't you see what you're doing?  You call `genButton(command=None,channel=None)`.  That creates an object where `self.command` is None.  You then do `embed = self.command()`.  How can that possibly work?  `self.command` is None.

Comment: @TimRoberts so how would I go about solving this? By taking out command and channel from the on_ready function where its added as a view? I deleted my previous comment as I realised I was speaking rubbish and I was confused with what you had written, my apologies

Comment: I DON'T KNOW WHAT `command` IS SUPPOSED TO BE.  Where does it come from?  You're using it.

Comment: `self.command` refers to what function is called when the button is pressed, eg the test function. As I've said, the inputs in `client.add_view(genButton(command=None,channel=None))` were added because I thought they were needed to use persistent buttons

Comment: OK, but if you haven't provided a function (which you have not done there), then you can't try to call it.  Do you need `if self.command: self.command()`?

Comment: Thanks for the help, i've now got a working solution for my problem